# Using a swift 3 framework in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift

I believe the answer is no, but I wanted to be certain. Can you compile a swift 2.3 app that contains a swift 3.0 framework?

Comment: Not yet. When Swift will reach ABI stability it will be possible to use a framework made with a different version of the language - but for now, it's not possible.

Comment: You can't use both, and I currently use Swift 3, however since it's still in the betas (and so is xcode 8) I recommend staying on Swift 2.3 if you currently have apps on the App Store to maintain. If you don't, then I suggest learning Swift 3 now so you can figure out the new stuff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no :/ As Apple said:

> Swift 3 is the primary development language supported within Xcode 8
>   so there are a couple notes to consider if you chose to continue using
>   Swift 2.3. First, Swift 2.3 and Swift 3 are not binary compatible so
>   your app's entire code base needs to pick one version of Swift.

[Source and more informations on the Apple Swift Blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36).

You will have to choose between 2.3 and 3.0. If you can, I think the best idea is to move directly to 3.0 (since 2.3 is just a "transitory" version).